# arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I have a scripts that was created some time ago, probably in an earlier version of Python. I have several Python programs to use and get different error. I guess that's to be expected.

Code snippet:

```
num_days = 7
today = datetime.today().isoformat(' ', 'seconds')
print (today)
td = datetime.today()
sd = td - timedelta(days= num_days)
start_date = sd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print ("Last Edited from: " + str(start_date))
```

```py
where_clause = "LAST_EDITED_DATE <= TO_DATE('{0}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') And LAST_EDITED_DATE > TO_DATE('{1}','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')".format(str(today), str(start_date))

for a, b in workspaces:
    arcpy.env.workspace = (database + "/" + a + "/" + b)
    database_path = arcpy.env.workspace
    fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in fc_list:
        print (fc_list)
        selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
        print(len(selection))
```

Error code using Python 3.6.10:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Scripts\PW_Attribute_Edits\PW_Attribute_Edits_QC.py", line 106, in <module>
    selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
  File "E:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 8754, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    raise e
  File "E:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 8751, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(*gp_fixargs((in_layer_or_view, selection_type, where_clause, invert_where_clause), True)))
  File "E:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 511, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).
```

Comment: The error message is pretty specific in that you have an invalid SQL expression.  Since you haven't provided how `today` and `start_date` are defined, it is hard for anyone to provide specific feedback on your SQL.

Comment: This has less to do with ArcPy than how Oracle parses dates, and how Python formats them. You should always use `datetime.datetime.strftime()` to format dates. If you `print` the `where_clause` value and try to apply it in a SQLDeveloper window, you will get the same root error.

Comment: Here is how the dates are defined in the script

# time frame for the Public Works last attribute edits
num_days = 7
today = datetime.today().isoformat(' ', 'seconds')
print (today)
td = datetime.today()
sd = td - timedelta(days= num_days)
start_date = sd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print ("Last Edited from: " + str(start_date))

Comment: This is better:

num_days = 7
today = datetime.today().isoformat(' ', 'seconds')
print (today)
td = datetime.today()
sd = td - timedelta(days= num_days)
start_date = sd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print ("Last Edited from: " + str(start_date))

Comment: @FSR, I just tried your code on an Oracle table with a date field, and it validated fine and successfully ran.  Unless you share some sample data that reproduces the issue or elaborate more on your data sources, I can't offer any other suggestions.

Comment: I'd use [fc] though there is no clear mentioning of this in a help. PRO makes it possible to work on a list of layers.

Comment: Thank you. I got the script to move beyond that line/issue.

Now, I am working on another oracle error.

RuntimeError: Underlying DBMS error [ORA-01861: literal does not match format string] [PW_UTILITIES.LineSurveyMeters03132023]

My guess is the featureclass name is too long.

Comment: It's not the filename, it is the date format of a field.

Comment: @bixb0012, thank you. The field it is reading is the Editor Tracking LAST_EDITED_DATE.

Comment: If this issue is solved, please post an answer (and then accept that answer as correct).  If  you have another question, post it as a new question.